# No figure numbers and no Figure caption title with memoir

Tags: floats, numbering, memoir

I would like to remove the Figure text and the figure numbering but I am not even able to get rid of the numbering. Anyone know how to this easily?

```
\documentclass[a6paper, 12pt]{memoir}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
    \caption{foo}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you considered loading the `caption` package and using `\caption*` instead of `\caption`?

Comment: Sounds like a plan if there is no built in Memoir approach :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could load the `caption` package, which provides a macro called `\caption*`, and replace

```
\caption{foo}
```

with

```
\caption*{foo}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it in `memoir`.

```
% memfigprob.tex  SE 571318
\documentclass[a6paper, 12pt]{memoir}
\newcommand{\fcaption}[1]{{\centering #1\par}%
  \addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{#1}%  % delete this if no LoF entry needed
  }
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure*}
\centering
THIS IS A PICTURE
    \caption{foo}
\fcaption{achoo}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

I have defined `\fcaption` to be used inside a `figure` which does what you want and, unlike the `caption` package's `\caption*` also puts an entry in the LoF. You can do something similar for captions in tables (say `\tcaption` with appropriate changes for the LoT entry). If you are not bothered by LoF or LoT entries then `\fcaption` without the `\addcontentsline...` will do for both.[image]

[image]